# Adding a polygon to mesh in cpp (using maya api interface)

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to add a polygon to a mesh in cpp, where only one edge of the polygon is exist in the mesh (only 2 points of the polygon are already exist in the mesh). I tried to use the "addPolygon" function, but it didn't worked because the mesh doesn't contain all the points of the polygon at the beginning. (The mesh is represented by a MFnMesh object and the polygon is represented by an array of MPoint objects)

Does anyone know how to add such a polygon to the mesh?

Comment: It helps if you add some example code to show where you're at so far --  it's hard for people to answer if they're not sure what you've already tried:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask